# How can I add columns with different sizes to a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datetime-sorted Dataframe with "Headlines". 
I want to group these "Headlines" by their date. 
So my plan was to create a Series with all the "Headlines" for each day. Then I wanted to append this Series to a new Dataframe with the date as the column name.

As the columns have different sizes, I used pd.concat() to add the series to the Dataframe. But it won't work either.

Examples:
[Input Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySqgQ.png)
, [Output Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pikTI.png)

```
df_sorted = df.sort_values('dates', ascending=False)
df_added = pd.DataFrame()
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
k = 0

for i in range(0, len(df_sorted)):
        if (df_sorted.iloc[i]['dates'] == df_sorted.iloc[i+1]['dates']):
                continue
        else:
                df1[df_sorted.iloc[i]['dates']] = df_sorted.iloc[k:i+1]['headlines']
                df_added = pd.concat([df_added,df1], axis=1)
                df1 = pd.DataFrame()
                k = i + 1
```

Comment: This would be simpler to answer, if instead you just share inputs and expected output

Comment: You cannot have such a jagged DataFrame, and moreover it will be confusing for further processing. What's your final goal? Is it to dump a Excel file in the above format?

Comment: My final goal is to save the headlines in an excel file in the above format and update this file every day.